# How to solve a 4th order PDE using Fourier spectral method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I would like to solve PDE in a numerical way (Fourier spectral method, actually). And I think I should find some particular solution of the equation to apply the method, but I don't know how.

The equation is:

$$\frac {\partial y}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^4 y}{\partial x^4} = 0.$$

I thought $y = e^{-12t} \sin{2x}$ might be a particular solution. So I used following modified MATLAB code:

(Originally, it was made to solve KdV equation, and it put particular solution of KdV equation to `u`. I just put the particular solution above to `u`.

```
%         FFT with integrating factor v = exp(-ik^3t)*u-hat.

% Set up grid and two-soliton initial data:
  N = 256; dt = .4/N^2; x = (2*pi/N)*(-N/2:N/2-1)';
  A = 2; B = -12; clf, drawnow, set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')
  u = sin(A*x)*exp(12*t);
  v = fft(u); k = [0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1]'; ik3 = 1i*k.^3;

% Solve PDE and plot results:
  tmax = 0.006; nplt = floor((tmax/25)/dt); nmax = round(tmax/dt);
  udata = u; tdata = 0; h = waitbar(0,'please wait...');
  for n = 1:nmax
    t = n*dt; g = -.5i*dt*k;
    E = exp(dt*ik3/2); E2 = E.^2;
    a = g.*fft(real( ifft(     v    ) ).^2);
    b = g.*fft(real( ifft(E.*(v+a/2)) ).^2);     % 4th-order
    c = g.*fft(real( ifft(E.*v + b/2) ).^2);     % Runge-Kutta
    d = g.*fft(real( ifft(E2.*v+E.*c) ).^2);
    v = E2.*v + (E2.*a + 2*E.*(b+c) + d)/6;
    if mod(n,nplt) == 0 
      u = real(ifft(v)); waitbar(n/nmax)
      udata = [udata u]; tdata = [tdata t];
    end
  end
  waterfall(x,tdata,udata'), colormap(1e-6*[1 1 1]); view(-20,25)
  xlabel x, ylabel t, axis([-pi pi 0 tmax 0 2000]), grid off
  set(gca,'ztick',[0 2000]), close(h), pbaspect([1 1 .13])
```

But it doesn't seem that it works pretty well.

Comment: What domain $\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$ ? What initial (and/or boundary) condition?

Comment: Taking the Fourier transform wrt $x$ we can solve the resulting ODE analytically to give $\hat{y}(k,t) = \hat{y}(k,0) e^{-(k^2+k^4)t}$ so the solution at any time $t$ can be obtain from two simple Fourier transforms: $$y(x,t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\mathcal{F}[y_0]e^{-(k^2+k^4)t}\right]$$ I'm assuming here the domain is $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$ and that $y(x,0)$ is given.

Comment: Well, any boundary condition or domain that suits this equation is fine, But  unfortunately I don't know how to set appropriate ones. What I gotta do is  to know how the fourier spectral method works for high-order linear PDEs.

Comment: Note that $e^{-12t}\sin(2x)$ is not a solution of the given PDE. You probably forgot the minus sign in front of $-y_{xx}$. A correct solution is $y(x,t) = e^{-(a^2+a^4)t}\sin(ax)$ so for $a=2$ we get $e^{-20t}\sin(2x)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to answer the question, but I stumbled upon it while researching the subject. This answer may help the next people working on this equation and using this code made by [Lloyd N. Trefethen](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html9) (`p27.m`)

As you said the code you used was made to solve the KdV equation which is really different from your equation. The Korteweg–de Vries is third-order nonlinear dispersive partial differential equation. It reads

$$ u_t + u u_x + u_{xxx} = 0$$

and can be rewritten as

$$ u_t+ \left(\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)_x + u_{xxx} = 0.$$

As explained in the comments, the code uses Fourier spectral methods coupled with the integrating factor method. The latter method is used to deal with the nonlinearity that you do not have in your equation. Here's the development leading to this code:

The Fourier transform of the last equation leads to

$$\hat{u}_t + \frac{i}{2}k\widehat{u^2} - i k^3 \hat{u} =0.$$

Now by multiplying by the integrating factor we get

$$e^{-ik^3t}\hat{u} + \frac{i}{2}e^{-ik^3t}k\widehat{u^2} - ie^{-ik^3t} k^3 \hat{u} =0.$$

Let $\hat{v} = e^{-ik^3t} \hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}_t = -ik^3\hat{v} + e^{-ik^3t}\hat{u}_t$, the initial problem becomes

$$\hat{v}_t + \frac{i}{2}e^{-ik^3t}k\widehat{u^2} = 0 $$

and in Fourier space

$$\hat{v}_t + \frac{i}{2}e^{-ik^3t}k\mathcal{F}\left(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(e^{ik^3t}\hat{v}\right)^2\right) = 0.$$

Add the Runge-Kutta scheme and you obtain the code above.

---

Back to your equation. The Fourier transform of

$$u_t - u_{xx} + u_{xxxx} = 0$$

is

$$\hat{u}_t + (k^2+k^4)\hat{u} = 0.$$

As mentioned in the comments above, given an initial condition, you can find an analytic solution of this equation. For the numerical side, a classical spectral code with a well chosen time step will work very well for this linear equation. You can also compute the solution given by [Winther](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html9) using any FFT algorithm.